# Why can't webrtc find the capturer it suggested?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, webrtc

I'm creating a `webrtc-based` voip app for windows in `C++`. I'm trying to initialize a `peerconnection`. I'm stuck at the part to fetch a camera. I'm using the following code to find a camera to start streaming media from (copied from the peerconnection client example):

```
rtc::scoped_ptr<cricket::DeviceManagerInterface> dev_manager(cricket::DeviceManagerFactory::Create());
if (!dev_manager->Init()) {
    LOG(LS_ERROR) << "Can't create device manager";
    return NULL;
}
std::vector<cricket::Device> devs;
if (!dev_manager->GetVideoCaptureDevices(&devs)) {
    LOG(LS_ERROR) << "Can't enumerate video devices";
    return NULL;
}
std::vector<cricket::Device>::iterator dev_it = devs.begin();
cricket::VideoCapturer* capturer = NULL;
for (; dev_it != devs.end(); ++dev_it) {
    capturer = dev_manager->CreateVideoCapturer(*dev_it);
    if (capturer != NULL)
        break;
}
```

`capturer` is empty after this procedure. I stepped through the code to see what was wrong. `dev_manager` is succesfully intialized, `devs` gets a single entry (my webcam) with a name:

```
"logitech HD webcam c270"
```

And an id:

```
"\\\\?\\usb#vid_046d&pid_0825&mi_00#7&2dbd1a82&1&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\\{bbefb6c7-2fc4-4139-bb8b-a58bba724083}"
```

But after the `CreateVideoCapturer()` call, `capturer` is still empty. I get a warning in the console saying:

```
Warning(webrtcvideocapturer.cc:175): Failed to find capturer for id: \\?\usb#vid_046d&pid_0825&mi_00#7&2dbd1a82&1&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\{bbefb6c7-2fc4-4139-bb8b-a58bba724083}
```

I checked if the id I get in `devs` and this one match and they do. The entire log for my app can be found in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GKHwtSmY). As you can see, right after trying to assign the camera as capturer and failing, the app crashes on an `assert(capturer != NULL)` call somewhere in `videosource.cc`.

The camera is not in use, nor is it defect. The `peerconnection` client example works perfectly and uses the same code. I think I'm missing some step in the initialization of `webrtc`, but I can't find which step.

#### edit with additional info

I'm debug stepping through the library now. In `webrtcvideocapturer.cc` around line 160 is the following code:

```
int num_cams = info->NumberOfDevices();
char vcm_id[256] = "";
bool found = false;
for (int index = 0; index < num_cams; ++index) {
  char vcm_name[256];
  int32 i = info->GetDeviceName(index, vcm_name, ARRAY_SIZE(vcm_name), vcm_id, ARRAY_SIZE(vcm_id));
  if (i != -1) {
    if (device.name == reinterpret_cast<char*>(vcm_name)) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (!found) {
  LOG(LS_WARNING) << "Failed to find capturer for id: " << device.id;
  factory_->DestroyDeviceInfo(info);
  return false;
}
```

There are two problems with this part. First of all, if I step into `info->NumberOfDevices()` it shows me that that function's only content is the line `return 0;`. I tried hard-coding 1 there, to at least get into the for loop. Then when I step into the `info->GetDeviceName()` call it shows me that the content of that function is `return -1;`.

These two functions are meant to be implemented by a class that inherits from `webrtc::VideoCaptureModule::DeviceInfo`, so there is clearly something not initialized that does needs to be initialized. What do I still need to do before trying to get a camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What libraries did you link?

Because Google WebRTC source codes are changing rapidly, it is difficult to track down issues to the source level.

But I remember the almost same problem occurred when I accidentally linked external capture module library (video_capture_module_impl ??) or (I'm not sure) omitted internal impl (video_capture_module_internal_impl ??).

Comment: This works, I still don't understand why, but I'm happy.

Comment: How have you solved that? I ma trying to do the same thing, I was able to build webrtc, but even the main example is not working, it is crashing perrconnection_client.exe